# Hibernate Inheritance mapping with an interface parent

Tags: xml, hibernate, groovy, interface, mapping

Using Groovy and Hibernate 4.3, I a have an Interface:

```
interface PaymentMethod {

}
```

an implementation:

```
class Salary implements PaymentMethod {

    private Long id

    private Integer value;

    protected Salary() {}

    public Salary(Integer value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    Integer getValue() {
        return value
    }
}
```

the following configuration:

```
<class name="sandbox.payroll.PaymentMethod" abstract="true">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="sequence"/>
    </id>

    <union-subclass name="sandbox.payroll.imp.Salary" table="SALARY">
        <property name="value" type="java.lang.Integer" column="VALUE" access="field"/>
    </union-subclass>
</class>
```

and hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set to create-drop in a hsqldb memory schema.

When I run a test I get a `org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [id] not found on sandbox.payroll.PaymentMethod`. The mapping seems ok based on the Hibernate Documentation and I can't understand what went wrong. Any hints?

UPDATE

1) Generator must be sequence in this case.

2) I was able to make it work by defining getId and setId on the interface, but I don't wanna do that since it is unnecessary to the domain design, which consists of an Employee that contains one of the PaymentMethod specialization:

```
class Employee {

    PaymentMethod paymentMethod

    (...)
}
```

It is a one-to-one relantionship in which Employee is the owner, so the id of PaymentMethod is irrelevant since it is the same of the Employee. Therefore, for the domain model, PaymentMethod don't need to expose any id, it is only a persistence detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens it is not possible to do that. In the last documentation of Hibernate(5.2), the Identifier Section says (bolds are mine):

> "Every entity **must** define an identifier. For entity inheritance hierarchies, >the identifier **must be defined just on the entity that is the root of the** >**hierarchy**."

(http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers)

Answer (score 0):

Given what's described, it seems like you're trying to tell Hibernate to look for an attribute / property called `id` at `sandbox.payroll.PaymentMethod`, which doesn't contain such attribute / property. So, in this case, an easy fix would be adding `getId` / `setId` to `sandbox.payroll.PaymentMethod`, which I assume is something you wouldn't like to do.

Could you give some more insight into what you're really trying to achieve here? Given what's described in [Hibernate documentation about inheritance](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete), it seems like the `id` should be declared for every `<union-subclass />`, instead of outside the `<union-subclass />` node, as you're trying to do here.

Are you trying to have something like an abstract class declared that would contain this `id` and avoid re-declaring it for every `<union-subclass />`?

Comment: Union-subclass don't work, even if all my subclasses defines id attributes hibernate complains that PaymentMethod should have an id despite even the fact that I declare it abstract. I think what I am trying to achieve is not possible.